# Symfony 2 left join with many to many relation ship got InvalidPathExpression error

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity-relationship

I have a many to many relationship in a symfony 2 project and i try to create a left join on it but I have an error. I've read hundred of doc and post but I can't find the solution. Hope you could help me to figure out :)

Here the error:

[Semantical Error] line 0, col 162 near 'users = u WHERE': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.

Here my relationship:

```
   AdminBundle\Entity\KeywordNeed:
     ...
manyToMany:
        users:
            targetEntity: User
            mappedBy: keywordNeeds
```

And the other entity:

```
    AdminBundle\Entity\User:
...
keywordOffers:
            targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\KeywordOffer
            inversedBy: users
            nullable: true
            joinTable:
                name: users_keywordoffer
                joinColumns:
                    user_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    keywordoffer_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
```

and finally the sql request I generate:

```
    SELECT distinct u  FROM AdminBundle\Entity\Network n 
INNER JOIN AdminBundle\Entity\User u WITH n.startup = u 
LEFT JOIN AdminBundle\Entity\KeywordOffer ko WITH ko.users = u 
 WHERE n.network = :oUser 
AND (u.lastName like '%blabla%' OR u.firstName like '%blabla%' OR u.company like '%blablaa%') 
AND ko in ('7','6')
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can just use field name as a glue for join insetad of using WITH:

```
SELECT distinct u FROM AdminBundle\Entity\Network n 
INNER JOIN AdminBundle\Entity\User u WITH n.startup = u 
LEFT JOIN u.keywordOffers ko
...
```

In fact With clause is useful when you want to add another joining constraint or to join two not related entities. If Network is also connected to users on startup field you can also enhance you DQL:

```
SELECT distinct u FROM AdminBundle\Entity\Network n 
INNER JOIN n.startup u 
LEFT JOIN u.keywordOffers ko
...
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly I had ever tried this and the result was not good. But I have found another way to do it. I have cut the request in two different requests. I filter first on my inner join and then I make another one with my results on the left join.